# Get XML child nodes when using DOM parser

Tags: java, android, xml, dom

I am using the `DOM` parser in `Java` and am trying to return the child node elements. Here is what my XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
  <group name="Recently Added">
    <item>
      <asset>138682</asset>
      <date>Mar 05, 2015</date>
      <artist>
        <![CDATA[Marlin G. Meharry, D.D.S]]>
      </artist>
      <album>
        <![CDATA[Career Day - Marlin G. Meharry, D.D.S]]>
      </album>
      <url>
        <![CDATA[http://web2.puc.edu/Departments/Media_Services/file/2015/CarDayMarlinGMeharryDDS.mp3]]>
      </url>
      <length>
        <![CDATA[36:48]]>
      </length>
    </item>
    <item>
      <asset>140705</asset>
      <date>Jan 01, 2000</date>
      <artist>
        <![CDATA[John Nunes]]>
      </artist>
      <album>
        <![CDATA[Educator of the Year]]>
      </album>
      <url>
        <![CDATA[http://web2.puc.edu/Departments/Media_Services/file/2015/2015-4-2LloydBest.mp3]]>
      </url>
      <length>
        <![CDATA[40:46]]>
      </length>
    </item>
  </group>
  <group name="Heubach Lectureship Series">
    <item>
      <asset>48041</asset>
      <date>Mar 07, 2009</date>
      <artist>
        <![CDATA[Barry C. Black, United States Senate Chaplain]]>
      </artist>
      <album>
        <![CDATA[Heubach Lecture]]>
      </album>
      <url>
        <![CDATA[http://web2.puc.edu/Departments/Media_Services/file/2009/HeubachLecture030709.mp3]]>
      </url>
      <length>
        <![CDATA[1:12:57]]>
      </length>
    </item>
  </group>
</body>
```

So, below my root element I have group nodes which are like arrays, as they hold item nodes. I need to get at the item nodes to get their data. Here is what I have come up with so far, but am still unsure where to go next:

```
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(in);

NodeList categoryList = doc.getElementsByTagName("group");
for (int categoryNo=0; categoryNo<categoryList.getLength(); categoryNo++) {

    //Element categoryNode = (Element)categoryList.item(categoryNo);

    Node node = categoryList.item(categoryNo);
    NodeList childNodes = categoryList.item(categoryNo).getChildNodes();
    for (int childNo = 0; childNo < childNodes.getLength(); childNo++) {

        Node childNode = childNodes.item(childNo);
        if (childNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            Element elem = (Element) childNode;

            Log.d(elem.getNodeValue(), "Zed");
        }


    }

}
```

**Any hints as to how to get those item nodes such as asset, artist, album, etc?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `elem` corresponds to the `item` element in the XML, you can retrieve a child element using `Element#getElementsByTagName(String elementName)`, similar to what you do to get the `group` elements. Then you can retrieve the content of the element using `Node#getTextContent()`. For instance:

```
Element elem = (Element) childNode;
NodeList assetNodes = elem.getElementsByTagName("asset");
if(assetNodes.getLength() > 0) {
    // get the text content of the first node
    String asset = assetNodes.item(0).getTextContent();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Now how could I get the "name" attribute of each group node?

Comment: @NicHubbard See the [API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/package-summary.html). You can retrieve an attribute value using `((Element)node).getAttribute("name")`